# Where do meteors usually spawn?

Tags: terraria

On Terraria I mined a shadow orb thus getting a meteor. When I destroyed another shadow orb today I couldn't find the new meteor. The first time it was located in the Left ocean. Where could it be now ?

Comment: Did you destroyed the shadow orb did you get the message? you don't get a Meteor every time you destroy a Shadow Orb, i know from experience as before entering Hard Mode i was destroying all the shadow orbs to farm loot and after beating the Eater of Worlds like 5 times i only ever gotten like 3 meteor messages, however you will always be guaranteed one on the first orb you destroyed (theory is that the Eater of Worlds "lands" in your world on it)

Answer (score 6):

They can land almost anywhere, but never within 25 blocks of a player, an NPC or a chest.

> This event always occurs off-screen, so the player will only see a message and the resulting crash site, but never the impact itself.
>
> [...]
>
> Meteorites can land anywhere, including Floating Islands, inside of a Chasm, or the Dungeon. Meteorites can even land at the bottom of a body of water. The Meteorite replaces dozens of blocks deep with Meteorite in a crater pattern. -- [Source](http://terraria.gamepedia.com/Meteorite_%28biome%29)

Answer (score 2):

It could have landed on a floating island. They are usually high enough in the sky that you'd not even notice. If you've walked from ocean to ocean and didn't see a meteor AND got the message that the meteor has landed, try looking up ^^

Answer (score 0):

Most commonly  if a section of the world is not discovered, the Meteor has a higher chance of landing there, if it did not... Sky Island would be your best bet. BEWARE! If it did land on a sky island most of it may get destroyed.